# Size of Ethereum transaction and its signature component?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, encryption

A couple of questions:

What is the average size of an Ethereum transaction in bytes (considering say a basic value transfer case).

Also, what is the size in bytes of the signature component of the transaction?

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer...

> Also, what is the size in bytes of the signature component of the transaction?

It's a `big.Int`, which can [vary in size](https://golang.org/pkg/math/big/).

```
type txdata struct {
    AccountNonce    uint64
    Price, GasLimit *big.Int
    Recipient       *common.Address `rlp:"nil"` // nil means contract creation
    Amount          *big.Int
    Payload         []byte
    V               *big.Int // signature
    R, S            *big.Int // signature
}
```

Source: [`transaction.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f7826270c9e87509fd7731ec64953a5e4761de0/core/types/transaction.go#L60)

---

> What is the average size of an Ethereum transaction in bytes
>   (considering say a basic value transfer case).

Note that there isn't a fixed limit for the size of a transaction. A soft limit is imposed by the size of the block, which itself is dependent on the gas limit (which itself can be changed). So an *overall* average would require work to determine.

But if we're talking about a value transfer case, then some of the complexities drop away. Looking at the above `txdata` structure, itself a member of an overall [`Transaction`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/5f7826270c9e87509fd7731ec64953a5e4761de0/core/types/transaction.go#L52) structure (at least in the Go implementation), you could go about summing the sizes of the independent parts. (I'm not sure how big the `common.Address` and byte array parts are, nor what is *exactly* passed as the transaction structure: the `Transaction` or the `txdata`. Someone else may know more.)

Comment: wait, what? the size in bytes of the signature = size in bytes of V, R, S = 1 + 32 + 32 = 65 bytes